# Making your own class 'Comparable'

Tags: java, comparable

I followed a tutorial, but failed to make my `Country` class `Comparable` for my `BST`.

Main:

```
BinarySearchTree A = new BinarySearchTree();
Country a = new Country("Romania", "Bucharest", 1112);
A.insert(a);
```

Country class:

```
public int compareTo(Object anotherCountry) throws ClassCastException {
    if (!(anotherCountry instanceof Country))
        throw new ClassCastException("A Country object expected.");
    String anotherCountryName = ((Country) anotherCountry).getName();  
    int i = this.name.compareTo(anotherCountryName);
    if(i < 0){
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

error:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object anotherCountry) throws ClassCastException {
    if (!(anotherCountry instanceof Country))
      throw new ClassCastException("A Country object expected.");
    String anotherCountryName = ((Country) anotherCountry).getName();  
    return this.name.compareTo(anotherCountryName);

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
```

Name clash: The method compareTo(Object) of type Country has the same erasure as compareTo(T) of type Comparable but does not override it    Country.java    /Lab2_prob 4/src    line 17 Java Problem

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method compareTo(Object) of type Country must override or implement a supertype method  Country.java    /Lab2_prob 4/src    line 17 Java Problem
```

and class:

```
public class Country implements Comparable<Country>{
    private String name;
    private String capital;
    private int area;

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
```

The type Country must implement the inherited abstract method Comparable.compareTo(Country)    Country.java    /Lab2_prob 4/src    line 2  Java Problem

Comment: Does your `Country` class extend `Comparable<Country>`?

Comment: What problem or error are you actually getting?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your `Country` class should implement `Comparable`:

```
public class Country implements Comparable<Country>
```

Then your `compareTo` method should look like this:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Country anotherCountry) {
    return this.name.compareTo(anotherCountry.getName());
}
```

Note the signature of `compareTo`. The parameter can (and must) be of type `Country`, not `Object`. This is required because of the generic type parameter on `Comparable`. The upside is you don't have to check the type anymore. The downside is you can only compare `Country` to other `Country` objects (or its subtypes), but in most cases this is what you want anyway. If not you have to change the type parameter, e.g. if you use `Comparable<Object>` the signature of `compareTo` can be `Object` again. You can read more about generics [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Comment: Just remembered `Comparable` is an interface. Sorry for the error.

Comment: Can you please check the erros i got after the fixes you suggested me? pretty please

Comment: @mic you are right, my bad. I'll edit it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

a [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) should return:

> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less
>   than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

However, your code is returning only -1 or 0, which is not correct; this implies that `this` can be less than the other object, or equal, but not greater!

There is no need to modify the values returned by `name.compareTo()` - you can just return them directly.